TCP/ip information for CLIENT/SERVER EXCHANGE distributed system
I am trying to create a server/client in a distributed system.
The server must print it's tcp/ip information and manually I have to enter it in the client side so the client can establish a tcp/ip connection
How can I do that in c?
Tried to playing with accept that gives us the client info and port but how do I do the opposite?
Sorry if this has been asked before.

Err, connect()? And [tag:udp] has nothing to do with it.

Hey, maybe I didn't phrase my question clearly.(Sorry for that)i want the server to print the information of his ip and then manually i will enter the Ip/port of the server so the client can join. @user207421.

So you need to call getsockname() on the listening socket and print the result. But this is no way to design or implement a distributed system. You are going to have to use a fixed port number, or some kind of registry like say Sun-RPC uses.

@user207421 I don't think getsockname() will be helpful. If you're listening on IPADDR_ANY to allow connections to any interface (which is the normal way), it will just show the address 0.0.0.0. You can get IP information from ifconfig -a, but you'll need to parse out the addresses and select the appropriate LAN interface.

Thanks for the suggestion, but the project requirements say that we need the server to print it's ip address port or whatever info it's needed for the many clients that will join. @Barmar can you recommend me something?Cheers!

@Barmar Well yes, I guess I meant to get the port if ephemeral. But I don't see how the server IP address can be such a mystery, or why the server needs to print it when there are utilities that already do so.

@user207421 It seems like they're trying to make this self-contained, rather than requiring users to perform manual steps to get the information needed to configure the clients. You're right that getsockname() is the correct way to get the port if it's assigned dynamically.
